# How do I scrape real time public transport timings using Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

https://www.ptv.vic.gov.au/next5/diva/10018306/line/9777/2

I am trying to get the timings/time(departing time) and destination, but the page refreshes every 60secs and I am unable to get that info.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from user_agent import generate_user_agent
from requests import get

headers = {'User-Agent': generate_user_agent(device_type="desktop", os=('mac', 'linux'))}
url = 'https://www.ptv.vic.gov.au/next5/diva/10004556/line/11613/2'
response = get(url)

html_soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
type(html_soup)
datatest = html_soup.find_all('div', class_='timetable')
print(type(datatest))
print(len(datatest))
```

I want to grab at least 3 upcoming timings and destination from the website.

Answer (score 1):

The realtime data is updated every minute using a request for JSON. It is easier to extract this information from the JSON data rather than attempting to scrape it from the rendered HTML. For example:

```
from datetime import datetime
import requests

r = requests.get("https://www.ptv.vic.gov.au/langsing/stop-services?stopId=10018306&direction=Altona&limit=20&mode=2")
json_reply = r.json()

for value in json_reply['values']:
    dt_departing = datetime.strptime(value['time_timetable_utc'], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
    departing = dt_departing.strftime("%I:%M%p")   # 12hour format
    line_name = value['platform']['direction']['line']['line_name']
    print(f'{departing} - {line_name}')
```

Would give you data starting:

```
05:57PM - 903 - Altona - Mordialloc (SMARTBUS Service)
06:14PM - 903 - Altona - Mordialloc (SMARTBUS Service)
06:31PM - 903 - Altona - Mordialloc (SMARTBUS Service)
06:41PM - 903 - Altona - Mordialloc (SMARTBUS Service)
06:57PM - 903 - Altona - Mordialloc (SMARTBUS Service)
07:09PM - 903 - Altona - Mordialloc (SMARTBUS Service)
07:20PM - 903 - Altona - Mordialloc (SMARTBUS Service)
07:30PM - 903 - Altona - Mordialloc (SMARTBUS Service)
07:42PM - 903 - Altona - Mordialloc (SMARTBUS Service)
07:51PM - 903 - Altona - Mordialloc (SMARTBUS Service)
08:06PM - 903 - Altona - Mordialloc (SMARTBUS Service)
08:20PM - 903 - Altona - Mordialloc (SMARTBUS Service)
08:32PM - 903 - Altona - Mordialloc (SMARTBUS Service)
08:44PM - 903 - Altona - Mordialloc (SMARTBUS Service)
08:59PM - 903 - Altona - Mordialloc (SMARTBUS Service)
09:14PM - 903 - Altona - Mordialloc (SMARTBUS Service)
09:30PM - 903 - Altona - Mordialloc (SMARTBUS Service)
09:45PM - 903 - Altona - Mordialloc (SMARTBUS Service)
10:00PM - 903 - Altona - Mordialloc (SMARTBUS Service)
10:15PM - 903 - Altona - Mordialloc (SMARTBUS Service)
10:36PM - 706 - Mordialloc - Aspendale - Edithvale - Chelsea
01:32AM - 706 - Mordialloc - Aspendale - Edithvale - Chelsea
02:51AM - 706 - Mordialloc - Aspendale - Edithvale - Chelsea
10:36PM - 706 - Mordialloc - Aspendale - Edithvale - Chelsea
```

The URL was found by watching the request that a browser made every 60 seconds. You can easily adjust the time by changing the [format string](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/datetime.html?highlight=strptime#strftime-and-strptime-behavior), for example to get the day of the week use `"%A %I:%M%p"`